# How to change the mail settings while using queue in laravel to send mail and notification

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am writing a code which changes the email setting configuration during runtime but I just can't get it to work while using a queue to send a email after API success and the application takes the default configuration from `.env` to send a email. So, is there a way to somehow use a dynamic email setting along with a queue?

```php
 public function mailSetting($email_settings){
       
        config(['mail.host' => $email_settings->smtp_host]);
        config(['mail.port' => $email_settings->smtp_port]);
        config(['mail.username' => $email_settings->smtp_username]);
        config(['mail.password' => $email_settings->smtp_password]);
        config(['mail.encryption' => $email_settings->smtp_encryption]);
        config(['mail.from.name' => $email_settings->smtp_username]);
        config(['mail.from.address' => $email_settings->from_mail]);
            }
```

Comment: use array constants in your config file & pass it by conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Although late, but above problem was solved by utilization of job to handle the queued mails where changing config variable will make it possible to send mail under the given mail configuration settings .

Comment: Can you kindly post a reference or some useful links as well?